# LARAVEL 5 :: Display 'username' on homepage?

Tags: authentication, laravel-5, register-globals

So the new version of Laravel has a login and register system already built in and so I've changed some fields in the register page and now want the 'username' to be displayed instead of the 'name' on the homepage after login. Does anyone have a clue where this is attributed? Have been searching endlessly for this. Thanks.

Comment: That should be pretty simple although we have no way to help you without seeing your code. Please add at least the view file for the homepage.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The file you are looking for, is the app view file. This file defines a *sample* basic template for your website.
It is located here: `resources/views/app.blade.php`
In your case, you need to change `{{ Auth::user()->name }}` to `{{ Auth::user()->username }}`

Answer (score 1):

**You can find logged user name with this below code**

in any blade template you just write

```
@if (Auth::user()->name=="user_name")
    //your code after prove authentication                       
@endif
```